# Clojure: Can you Concat within a Recursive Function?

Tags: recursion, clojure

```
(defn recurse_fun       ;assume user types in (recurse_fun '(true false true) "")
   [input final]    

 (cond
  (empty? input) (System/exit 0) ;at this point final should equal (false true false)
  )

(cond
  (= 'false (first input)) (recurse_fun (rest input) (concat 'true final))

   ;^ recurse with new parameters of the rest of input and true concated with previous final

  (= 'true (first input)) (recurse_fun (rest input) (concat 'false final))

  ;^ recurse with new parameters of the rest of input and false concated with previous final

 )
```

I want final to equal "false true false" when (System/exit 0) is called. I believe this has to do something with concat. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why it is `cond` at first statment ? is it should use `if` instead ?

Comment: `(cond x y)` macroexpands to `(if x y)`

Answer (score 0):

couple issues here:

- you should use `cons` to put an element to a list
- you need a stop condition for this recursive function, using `if` in this case
- you'd better using `recur` instead of same function name in the function body

```lisp
    (defn recurse_fun       
       [input final]    

     (if (empty? input)  ;an `STOP` condition for recursive call
        final ;final value to be return
        (cond
          (= 'false (first input)) (recur (rest input) (cons 'true final )) ; pls use cons instead of concat
          ; usually in Clojure use `recur `
          (= 'true (first input)) (recur (rest input) (cons 'false final )) ; I guess it is a typo for your ?
         )
    ))
```

Comment: awesome thanks. why use cons over concat? And why does my cond stop condition not work?

Comment: `System.exit(0)` will quit current process instead of quit current function and `return final value`. `cons` put an element to a list/vector ,but `concat` is concatenating collections (means collections as input ) https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat